# Why instance variables can be modified through a field reader with the << operator?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following class.

```
class Test
  attr_reader :word
  def initialize(word)
    @word = word
  end

  def append_word(token)
    word << token
  end
end
```

Consider a sample usage of the class.

```
2.4.0 :001 > t = Test.new('Hello')
 => #<Test:0x007f7f09902970 @word="Hello"> 
2.4.0 :002 > t.append_word(' world!')
 => "Hello world!" 
2.4.0 :003 > t.word
 => "Hello world!" 
2.4.0 :004 >
```

I am new to Ruby. I don't understand why I can use the `append_word` instance method to modify the instance variable `@word` of a Test instance. `word` in append_word seems to be a field reader. My understanding is that a field reader is for reading only. How can `word << token` in `append_word` modify the value of `@word` in a Test instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `@word` references an object in memory. This object happens to be a `Hello!` string. Your class does not allow to (easily) set a new object for your `@word` instance variable, but nothing currently stops you from modifying the object directly. If you wish for the object to not be modifiable, you could `.freeze` it:

```
class Test
  attr_reader :word
  def initialize(word)
    @word = word.freeze
  end

  def append_word(token)
    word << token
  end
end

> Test.new("Hello").append_word("world!")
# FrozenError (can't modify frozen String)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your post answered my question. However, it brought up another. Does Ruby guarantee that `word`, the field reader, refers to the exact same object referred by `@word` instead of a copy of the object referred by `@word`?

Comment: Yes, `attr_reader :word` is the same as `def word; @word; end`

Comment: Technically, Ruby does have some types that are not full objects (by the fact their values are not references), though they behave as objects for most intents and purposes. For example, if `@word` is a small integer, `word` will return a copy and not a reference (as these objects are never referenced). However, since all such quasi-objects are immutable, there is no situation where a copy will behave differently than a reference, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @Amadan true, also worth mentioning that in case of these immutable objects, calling `@word` also returns a copy of `@word`, therefore adding a `attr_reader` does not really change how you interact with underlying value.

Comment: @Amadan Does Ruby guarantee that all mutable objects are passed by reference?

Comment: @engineersmnky: Neither of those is mutation, it is reassignment. In one case you are reassigning a local variable; in the other, you are reassigning the instance variable. This would behave identically with real objects, not just quasi-objects, and since it is not about mutation, it doesn't invalidate Martin's point.

Comment: @IsaacTo Yes. What I was talking above is more of a technical curio, as it should almost never impact your code (the only exception I know is you can't define methods on `Integer` instances, like you can on most of the other objects in Ruby -- `k = "foo"; def k.bang; self + "!"; end; k.bang == "foo!"` works, but not if `k=1337` -- but I've never ever needed that).

Comment: If you have been following the comments of this post, you may be interested in a new post,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294842/why-ruby-doesnt-allow-setting-a-local-variable-using-an-expression-containing-a,  I have made. The new post is related @engineersmnky's comment.