# Why Ruby doesn't allow setting a local variable using an expression containing a field reader with the same name as the local variable?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code.

```
class A
  attr_reader :n

  def initialize
    @n = 1
  end

  def set_local_n
    n = 10
  end

  def using_field_reader_locally
    n + 100
  end

  def using_field_reader_to_set_local_x
    x = n + 1000
  end

  def using_field_reader_to_set_local_n
    n = n + 1000  # This line raises a NoMethodError. Why?
  end
end
```

Why would the commented line produce an error? Why Ruby doesn't allow setting a local variable, `n` in this case, using an expression containing a field reader with the same name as the local variable? Why would all other instance methods run without any problem but `using_field_reader_to_set_local_n` produce an error.

Please note that I am NOT intending to define `n` locally in `using_field_reader_to_set_local_n` with an expression involving the locally defined `n` in `set_local_n`. I am intending to define `n` locally in `using_field_reader_to_set_local_n` with an expressing involving the field reader of `@n`. The definition of `set_local_n` is for showing that `n` can be defined locally while a field reader named `n` exists.

Comment: @TomLord I think you misinterpreted my intent. I am not trying to use a local `n` in another method, `set_local_n`, to define the `n` in `using_field_reader_to_set_local_n`. I intend the `n` in the right side of `n = n + 1000` in `using_field_reader_to_set_local_n` to be the field reader of `@n`. Although I didn't use `attr_accessor :n`, I used `attr_reader :n` to make `n` an field reader. Only because `n` is field reader, running `using_field_reader_locally` is possible. I put up `set_local_n` merely to illustrate that `n` can be set as a local variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look closely, the `NoMethodError` isn't about there being no method `n`, but method `+` for `NilClass`.

In this statement:

```
n = n + 1000
```

Ruby has to decide what `n` is. As you are assigning something to it (`n =`) it's not a method. If you wanted to call the `n=` method, you had to specify an explicit receiver (`self.n =`).

So it has to be a variable. In this case local variable.

---

Now to make sense of something like:

```
n = n
```

Ruby ends up assigning `nil` to `n`. This has to do with the internals having to put a placeholder for a variable name that is being assigned.

---

So when you do:

```
n = n + 1000
```

What happens is:

1. Create a new local variable `n` with placeholder value (`nil`).
2. Attempt to assign to it whatever is on the right.
3. Calculate what is on the right - `nil + 1000`.
4. `nil` doesn't have a `+` method so an error is raised.

---

To do what you wanted to do, you have to explicitly reference the instance variable for its value:

```
n = @n + 1000
```

Or explicitly call the attribute reader:

```
n = self.n + 1000
```

Comment: To me, you post seems to be be right answer. However, the interpretation of `n` on the right side the equal sign in `n = n + 1000` seems to be a bit strange to be. What you are saying is that the interpretation of `n` in `n + 1000` is determined by `n` being in the left side of the equal sign. This way of interpreting is different than the way used in other languages I encountered. Can you elaborate in the rules for this kind of interpretation? Can you find documentation for these rules?

Comment: @IsaacTo within the same scope, the same identifier has to refer to the same thing, unless you explicitly change what it's referring to. And as evaluation is top to bottom and left to right, the attempt at assignment is encountered first. At that point the decision of what `n` is has to be made. Can you give me an example of a language where the same identifier used in the same scope refers to different things?

Comment: A bare reference like `foo` could either be a receiverless argumentless message-send (e.g. equivalent to `self.foo()`) or a local variable dereference. Since you can easily tell Ruby that it is a message-send (by either adding a receiver like `self.foo` or adding an argument list like `foo()`), if there is an ambiguity, Ruby always prefers to interpret it as a local variable dereference. So, what is a local variable? A local variable is created when an assignment to a bare identifier is *parsed*: `if false then foo = 42 end; foo #=> nil`. `foo` is defined as local variable, but not initialized

Comment: @ndnenkov No, I can't give you an example. My understanding of this particular aspect of a computer language was incorrect. I tried similar code in C, and the behavior was similar. Thanks for answer and explanation.